# Jquery - Detect click options disabled HTML select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

```js
$(function(){

 $("select:option").on('click', this, function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("a");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Options 1</option>
  <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Options 2</option>
  <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Options 3</option>
  <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Options 4</option>
</select>
```

I need to check with Jquery, if the user clicked on an option of the selector is disabled, if user clicked display a **alert()**.

**Example:** A select several options, the options in this select to have a value of 0 is disabled, but if the user clicks on any of these options disabled, we show **an alert()**.

```
<select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Options 1</option>
  <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Options 2</option>
  <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Options 3</option>
  <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Options 4</option>
</select>
```

*I would greatly appreciate your help!*

Comment: Do you want to allow them to actually select the disabled option, or just detect them _trying_ to select one?

Comment: Also, what is the least modern browser you need to support?

Comment: I need to show the options disabled, the user may select them, but if you try it, and select one of these options disabled, show a message on an alert, such option is not permitted for any reason ... and work for all current browsers and phones.

Comment: `<option>` tag's don't accept events cross browser and you can't select a disabled option either. Why would you ever need this? What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve? Also note your jQuery selectors don't make any sense. There is no `:option` selector and `this` is the `document`

Comment: Case eg: I need to let the user know that there are other options available, but for some of these options may not be enabled to let you know with a message, for example, to select one of these you should contact an administrator.

Comment: You can't do any of that with a `disabled` option. All you can do is see it ... that's why it's disabled

Comment: It is understood perfect, that alternative or solution I can recommend in this case?

Comment: Depends on why you need it disabled in the first place. Could just remove disabled ones and put a list somewhere ... *if you need 1,2,3 ..contact admin"*

Comment: For example a panel of administration, user with role editor, the user can only apply some status to a published news options ('enable', 'disable', 'delete', 'suspend'), the user can only enable but you can not make other changes to want to do, show a modal window with a form explaining the reason why you want to choose some options not allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    $(function(){
        var options_sel_idx = 0;

        $("#options").on("change", this, function(event) {
            if($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).hasClass("disabled")) {
                alert("a");
                this.selectedIndex = options_sel_idx;
            } else {
                options_sel_idx = this.selectedIndex;
            }
        });
    });
    <style type="text/css">
        .disabled {color:#808080;}
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select name="options" id="options">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Options 1</option>
      <option value="0" class="disabled">Options 2</option>
      <option value="0" class="disabled">Options 3</option>
      <option value="0" class="disabled">Options 4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, is exactly what I needed to do.